# How to ensure that data submitted is a valid numerical pair?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I receive a string.
It should be in the format:

```
number,number
```

for example:

```
34.798,52.123
```

How can I verify that the number is in this format ? I need to assign it to some vars, and do some calculation. But since it is javascript (node.js), someone may submit a function instead and try to make my app invoke it. How do I verify that a submitted string is in the above format ?

I've considered the following approach:

```
function checkIfValid(input){
    var result = false;
    input = input.trim();
    var tokens = input.split(",");
    if(tokens.length==2){
        if(!isNaN(tokens[0]&&!isNaN(tokens[1]){
            result = true;
        }
    }
   return result;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this ? Can it be hacked ?

Comment: You may find the javascript `parseFloat` function useful.

Answer (score 0):

check for invariance across `parseFloat`

```
function checkIfValid(input){
    input = input.trim();
    var tokens = input.split(",");
    if(tokens.length === 2){
        var t0 = tokens[0];
        var t1 = tokens[1];
        return parseFloat(t0) == t0 && parseFloat(t1) == t1;
    }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JSON.parse` (after wrapping in `[`...`]`) and then check you got an array of two numbers:

```
var x = null;
try { x = JSON.parse("[" + data + "]"); } catch (err) { x = null; }
if (x && x.constructor === Array && x.length === 2 &&
    typeof x[0] === "number" && typeof x[1] === "number") {
  ... data is ok ...
} else {
  ... data is invalid ...
}
```

this approach also scales to other more complex cases.

The only annoying thing is that certain valid numbers for Javascript are not valid for JSON (for reasons I don't understand). For example "1." is not valid JSON (a digit is mandatory after the decimal point). You also cannot use NaNs and infinity values because that's also invalid in JSON.

Comment: Is this better than using isNan ?

Comment: @John: "this" what? Anyway you made me remember that also NaNs and infinities are not accepted in JSON (also no idea why). If something you parsed with `JSON.parse` is of type "number" you can be sure it's not a NaN.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the edge case of `isNaN('') == false`; this is because `''` is converted into a numerical value of `0` which can be represented.

You should parse the values first using `parseFloat()`:

```
function checkIfValid(input)
{
    var parts = input.split(',');

    return parts.length == 2 && parts.every(function(part) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(part));
    });
}
```